# Matching anything but the word, regex issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Given this messy string:

```
66,"Hi":"11.00","sth":"187,"Hi":"13.00"[5]"53","target":{"sth2"
```

I want to match `13.00` and  `sth2` (I need to ignore the `Hi` value of `11.00`).

My regex `"Hi":"(.{0,5})".+"target":{"(.*)"` can't do it because it matches the most left value of `Hi`, here: `11.00`

I'm looking for solution that would disallow the existance of `Hi` word between `Hi` itself and the word `target`.

Comment: Will `Hi` always appear twice, or must the regex account for the possibility of if occurring once **or** twice?

Comment: `Hi` may actually appear several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your regex to the following:

```
"Hi":"(.{0,5})"(?:(?!"Hi").)+"target":{"(.*)"
```

The only difference here is to change `.+` to `(?:(?!"Hi").)+`.  The `(?!"Hi")` is a negative lookahead that will fail if the next characters are `"Hi"`, so by putting this just before the `.` in the repetition it will ensure that no occurrences of that string are matched as a part of the `.+`.

Example:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'"Hi":"(.{0,5})"(?:(?!"Hi").)+"target":{"(.*)"')
>>> text = '66,"Hi":"11.00","sth":"187,"Hi":"13.00"[5]"53","target":{"sth2"'
>>> regex.search(text).groups()
('13.00', 'sth2')
```

This is a good generic way to add this type of requirement to a regex, but in your case you could also just put a `.*` at the beginning of your current regex.  This will greedily match as many characters as possible at the beginning of the string, so you will match the rightmost occurrence of `"Hi"`.